# Encode with JSON or pickle to a Variable Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode, pickle

I know it is possible to encode a Python object to a file using

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(obj, file)
```

or you can do nearly the same using JSON, but the problem is, these all encode or decode to a file, is it possible to encode an object into a string or bytes **variable** instead of a **file**?

I am running Python 3.2 on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use [`pickle.dumps(obj)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) or [`json.dumps(obj)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps).